# What kind of directory shoud I search to look for mapreduce source code in spark?

Tags: github, apache-spark

I'm studying about mapreduce and spark, and I curious about how spark process the mapreduce work. Accordingly, I'm searching that in 'https://github.com/apache/spark', but Watching that site, I couldn't get any clue about which directory should I search to see mapreduce source code.

I mean in following code, there are .flatMap(), .map() and .reduceByKey() function. Definitely, I want to see source code about these function.

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://...")
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                 .map(word => (word, 1))
                 .reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic abstraction in Spark is the `RDD`. If you look in `core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala` you can find [`map()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L364), [`flatMap()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L373), and [`filter()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L381), amongst others.

But they are not terribly exciting.